# Should we ask popular but easy questions?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic questions are not so basic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/basic-questions-are-not-so-basic)

[This search for "sneek vs sneak"](https://www.google.com/search?q=sneek%20vs%20sneak) points to a couple of Yahoo! Answers posts, like [this one](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080627025508AAgXWOO). There are many popular but simple English questions like these that point to Yahoo! Answers posts. These posts are good enough to answer the question, but I think this site can provide much better answers.

In other words, they fall here on Jeff/Borror0's [flowchart for answering simple questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/):

[image: answering simple questions flowchart]

Should we ask these popular but easy questions?

Comment: I am pretty sure the example you give would be closed as general reference.

Comment: @KitFox - Yup. I'm asking if we shouldn't close these types of questions given that (1) they are very popular and (2) we can give better answers than what's available to the casual Googler.

Comment: Is that an ELU question that was closed, or just the possibility of a question that you're thinking of? Just because it is on Yahoo answers, doesn't mean it's a good -or- bad question. (that one happens to be a general 'bad' question that a dictionary would answer...'sneek' ain't a word). Are you asking 'should' or 'could'? You -can- always try. I don't think you should bother asking that particular question here just because it's popular.

Comment: @Mitch - I'm asking about what our general policy should be regarding these questions. I haven't asked and don't intend to ask the sample "sneek vs sneak" question.

Comment: If you want to discuss this generally, I think you might just add comments in [the existing discussion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/basic-questions-are-not-so-basic).

Comment: @KitFox - Ah, that's what I'm talking about. Let's close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: You can also delete this question, as it doesn't have up-voted answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I forget if the linked question showed up as a possible duplicate as I was typing this up. If not, we should [leave this as a duplicate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) of the existing question.